# Xtext get the absolute path of the generated files

Tags: runtime, xtext

I want to access the file generated by Xtext  to compile it automatically. So I need its absolute path. It's enough to get the absolute path of the current project at run-time. Any idea how I can get it?
I am working inside the "MyDslGenerator" Class. I tried to get it from the "resource" in
    `override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa)` 
but couldn't find it.

Help is highly appreciated.

I ended up using this code:

```
var uri = (fsa as IFileSystemAccessExtension2).getURI(fileName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use the Interface `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IFileSystemAccessExtension2`. the passed IFileSystemAccess may implement this interface too.